# Ipad App Photo Save in Photos folder

Tags: ios, ipad

I have develop the ipad application. In that I have download photo option. I need to save photo on ipad Photos folder when we click on download button. Any one can please help me to solve How to save photo from ipad app yo ipad device photo album.

Thanks,
Prabhas.

Answer (score 0):

First Add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

```
-(void)buttonMethod:(UIButton *) Sender
{
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size);
                [self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
                UIImage *attachimage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:[NSData data]];
                UIImage *viImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                attachimage = viImage;
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: okay ... but don't forget to add #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: Patel is there any way to save Videos as well as pdfs to ipad from app?

Comment: @Prabhas- WELCOME best way is if my answer is help u then accept it and ask for videos as second QUESTION :) thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortest way (tested on both ios simulator and on ios device)

1. You can use this function:

   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);

You only need completionTarget, completionSelector and contextInfo if you want to be notified when the image is done saving, otherwise you can pass in nil.

if you want to save it to a custom album you can go through a good tutorial i found at

> http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/